# POST query to access table data on a website (Python)

Tags: python, post, web-scraping, request, response

I want to use [this website](https://www.patricbrc.org/view/Taxonomy/2#view_tab=genomes&filter=eq(host_name,%22Human%2C%20Homo%20sapiens%22)) to extract data from, however this website doesn't have an API to facilitate easy data extraction. So there is a "table" on the website which contains the data however this table is spread over multiple pages and the download option doesn't support "bulk" download. So I want to figure out a way to download this through Python. 
I figured out that I could do this with a post request. What I did is I started at page 1 and then click on the "next page" button and watched the network tab, this gave me:

```
Request URL:https://www.patricbrc.org/api/genome/
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK
Remote Address:128.173.97.11:443
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade

Response Headers
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:https://www.patricbrc.org
Access-Control-Expose-Headers:facet_counts,x-facet-count,Content-Range,X-Content-Range,ETag
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Range:items 200-399/45999
Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8
Date:Sat, 26 Aug 2017 09:36:40 GMT
ETag:W/"8ac0b-cFdEBUwfdiyTQm/gpJHYzQ"
Server:nginx/1.9.1
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
Vary:Origin, Accept
Vary:Accept-Encoding
X-Powered-By:Express

Request Headers
Accept:application/javascript, application/json, application/json
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language:nl-NL,nl;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:82
Content-Type:application/rqlquery+x-www-form-urlencoded
Cookie:sprod=hZ36nWTBiHHaDwdAhCChFGZo; _ga=GA1.2.582935779.1503602311; _gid=GA1.2.174755110.1503602311; _gat=1
Host:www.patricbrc.org
Origin:https://www.patricbrc.org
Range:items=200-399
Referer:https://www.patricbrc.org/view/Taxonomy/2
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.101 Safari/537.36
X-Range:items=200-399

Request Payload
eq(taxon_lineage_ids,2)&eq(host_name,%22Human%2C%20Homo%20sapiens%22)&sort(-score)
Name
genome/
```

To see what changes after a page switch I did this again (so again clicked to "next page" button).

```
Request URL:https://www.patricbrc.org/api/genome/
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK
Remote Address:128.173.97.11:443
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade

Response Headers
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:https://www.patricbrc.org
Access-Control-Expose-Headers:facet_counts,x-facet-count,Content-Range,X-Content-Range,ETag
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Range:items 400-599/45999
Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8
Date:Sat, 26 Aug 2017 09:44:24 GMT
ETag:W/"5dc73-ODopjbbyl5M2vUJvUGN0Gw"
Server:nginx/1.9.1
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
Vary:Origin, Accept
Vary:Accept-Encoding
X-Powered-By:Express

Request Headers
Accept:application/javascript, application/json, application/json
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language:nl-NL,nl;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:82
Content-Type:application/rqlquery+x-www-form-urlencoded
Cookie:sprod=hZ36nWTBiHHaDwdAhCChFGZo; _ga=GA1.2.582935779.1503602311; _gid=GA1.2.174755110.1503602311
Host:www.patricbrc.org
Origin:https://www.patricbrc.org
Range:items=400-599
Referer:https://www.patricbrc.org/view/Taxonomy/2
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.101 Safari/537.36
X-Range:items=400-599

Request Payload
eq(taxon_lineage_ids,2)&eq(host_name,%22Human%2C%20Homo%20sapiens%22)&sort(-score)
```

So the important things which changed (in my opinion) during the post request when going from page 1 --> 2 and from page 2 --> 3 were:

- **response header** Content-Range:*items 200-399/45999* --> Content-Range:*items 400-599/45999*
- **request header** Range:*items=200-399* --> Range:*items=400-599*
- **request header** X-Range:*items=200-399* --> X-Range:*items=400-599*

This is what the website says:

- page 1: 1 - 200 of 45999 results (but posts for 0-199, not shown above)
- page 2: 201 - 400 of 45999 results (but posts for 200-399, see above)
- page 3: 401 - 600 of 45999 results  (but posts for 400-599, see above)

I have **zero** knowledge about reading these POST request. But I guess there should be a way to say:

```
requests.post(some url) and extract the total page numbers (or number of genomes and devide these by the max number per page, which is 200 see post requests).
```

And then something like:

```
for page_numb in range(page_numbers):
    r = requests.post(some_url...... + page_numb)
    #extract the information from the table
```

FINALLY the question :)
I'm not able to figure out how to set up a POST request like

```
p1 = requests.post(https://www.patricbrc.org/api/genome/... 0-199)
p2 = requests.post(https://www.patricbrc.org/api/genome/... 200-399)
etc...
```

(And I hope that the reponse will contain the table data seperated by some delimiter)

---

The code I tried:

```
import requests
import json

url = 'https://www.patricbrc.org/api/genome/'
payload = {"eq(taxon_lineage_ids,2)&eq(host_name,%22Human%2C%20Homo%20sapiens%22)&sort(-score)"}
headers = {
    "X-Range": "items=0-199",
    "Range": "items=0-199",
    "content-type": "application/json"}


r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)
print(r)
```

***This code isn't working but I guess it should be something like this.*** 
I know I should post the payload as a JSON but I don't know how to translate `eq(taxon_lineage_ids,2)&eq(host_name,%22Human%2C%20Homo%20sapiens%22)&sort(-score)` into a JSON, whith it's key:value pairs.

Comment: from header `Content-Range` you can extract total items, by defining header `X-Range` and `Range` you can request a particular page.

Comment: Could you please answer with an example, that would be great (as I said I have no knowlegde about creating such a request) @sKwa Further the request payload should be used too because there was a filtering for "humans"

Comment: See the code I added, I think it should be something like that but it isn't working :( @sKwa

Comment: right direction, but it should be done in two steps: first step - get a Cookie, after it with a Cookie get data. I will try to show it, but later.

Comment: That would be very nice! I kinda understand this but using cookies is probably way over my head. @sKwa

Comment: I really want to figure this out, have been tyring this for like a week. If you don't have time to write an answer maybe you have some reference material I could understand? @sKwa

Comment: Sorry, but I can't give you a reference, its just experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a source code(its ugly code, but its just example, I recommend you to do it with `request.Session`):

```
import sys
import json
import requests

URL = 'https://www.patricbrc.org/view/Taxonomy/2'
API = 'https://www.patricbrc.org/api/genome/'

# we need to get a Cookie
response = requests.get(URL)
if response.status_code != 200:
    sys.exit('Cookie request failed')
cookie = response.headers['Set-Cookie'].split(';')[0]
etag   = response.headers['ETag']

# now with cookie request a data
headers = {
    'Host'            : 'www.patricbrc.org',
    'Accept'          : 'application/javascript, application/json, application/json',
    'Accept-Language' : 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
    'Referer'         : 'https://www.patricbrc.org/view/Taxonomy/2',
    'X-Range'         : 'items=200-399',  # your pages
    'Range'           : 'items=200-399',  # your pages
    'Content-Type'    : 'application/rqlquery+x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Cookie'          : '{};'.format(cookie),
    'ETag'            : etag
}

data = 'eq(taxon_lineage_ids,2)&eq(host_name,%22Human%2C%20Homo%20sapiens%22)&sort(-score)'
response = requests.post(API, headers=headers, data=data)
if response.status_code != 200:
    sys.exit('API request failed')
data = json.loads(response.text)

# test data
row200 = data[0]
print 'FAMILY     :', row200['family']
print 'GC_CONTENT :', row200['gc_content'] 
print 'GENUS      :', row200['genus']
print 'ORDER      :', row200['order']
```

**Output of `test data` block:**

```
FAMILY     : Eubacteriaceae
GC_CONTENT : 38.78
GENUS      : Eubacterium
ORDER      : Clostridiales
```

**EDIT**
You don't need a cookie, this works fine too:

```
import json
import requests

API = 'https://www.patricbrc.org/api/genome/'

# now with cookie request a data
headers = {
    'Host'            : 'www.patricbrc.org',
    'Accept'          : 'application/javascript, application/json, application/json',
    'Accept-Language' : 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
    'Referer'         : 'https://www.patricbrc.org/view/Taxonomy/2',
    'X-Range'         : 'items=200-399',  # your pages
    'Range'           : 'items=200-399',  # your pages
    'Content-Type'    : 'application/rqlquery+x-www-form-urlencoded',
}

query = 'eq(taxon_lineage_ids,2)&eq(host_name,%22Human%2C%20Homo%20sapiens%22)&sort(-score)'
response = requests.post(API, headers=headers, data=query)
data = json.loads(response.text)
```

Comment: I was wrong, you don't need a cookie, you can skip this step.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to embed this: https://www.patricbrc.org/view/Taxonomy/2#view_tab=amr&filter=keyword(test) in your code? So the keyword. I tried to add params = "{keyword: test}" but that doesn't work :( @sKwa